# Image of operator in separable Hilbert-space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert-space, $\{e_i\}$ a complete orthonormal basis and $L$ an operator with $$L:H\to H,$$ $$L(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{\langle x,e_i\rangle}{i}e_i.$$

Why is $$L(H)=\{y\in H:\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}i^2|\langle y,e_i\rangle|^2<\infty\}?$$

Thanks to the comment:

$$|\langle Lx,e_i\rangle| = \frac{|\langle x,e_i\rangle|}{i}$$

and hence

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}i^2|\langle Lx,e_i\rangle|^2=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|\langle x,e_i\rangle|^2=\|x\|<\infty$$

So $$\{y\in H|\exists x\in H : Lx = y\} = \{y\in H|\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}i^2|\langle y,e_i\rangle|^2<\infty\}$$

Comment: Can you show that the LHS is contained in the RHS? First calculate $\langle L(x),e_i\rangle$ for each $x \in H$ and $i$. Once you do this, verify that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty i^2 |\langle L(x),e_i\rangle|^2 < \infty$ for all $x$. If you are able to make some progress, kindly edit this into your post.

Comment: Oh, hey @newbie just noticed your edit. You still need to do the reverse part as well : if $\sum_{i=1}^\infty i^2 |\langle y,e_i\rangle|^2 < \infty$, then think about the sum $z = \sum_{i=1}^\infty i \langle y,e_i\rangle e_i$ : is $z \in H$ as a well defined element? What is $L(z)$? If you are done then feel free to write a self-answer.